# Delete duplicate rows if two variables match PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have two variables $faceplateInstalled and $faceplateExists and I print them into two columns

```
Faceplate Exists    Faceplate Instaled  
1                           1   
1                           0   
1                           1   
0                           0   
1                           1   
1                           0   
1                           1   
1                           1   
0                           0   
0                           0   
1                           0
```

Is there a way to remove entries where I have 1 and 1 in a same row?

This is a query I use:

```
"SELECT F.id AS faceplateId, PR.premiseId, ComposeAddressFromPAF( PR.postAddressId ) AS fullAddress, " .
            "   IF( F.id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0 ) AS faceplateExists, " .
            "   IFNULL( F.installed, 0 ) AS faceplateInstalled, " .
            "   PR.siteId, S.NAME AS siteName " .
            "FROM ho_crm_premise PR " .
            "   LEFT JOIN ho_faceplate F ON F.premiseId = PR.premiseId " .
            "   INNER JOIN bcube_site S ON S.SITEID = PR.siteId " .
            "WHERE S.SITEID";
```

and this is whole function

```
function GetFaceplates( $siteId )
    {
        $sSql =
            "SELECT F.id AS faceplateId, PR.premiseId, ComposeAddressFromPAF( PR.postAddressId ) AS fullAddress, " .
            "   IF( F.id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0 ) AS faceplateExists, " .
            "   IFNULL( F.installed, 0 ) AS faceplateInstalled, " .
            "   PR.siteId, S.NAME AS siteName " .
            "FROM ho_crm_premise PR " .
            "   LEFT JOIN ho_faceplate F ON F.premiseId = PR.premiseId " .
            "   INNER JOIN bcube_site S ON S.SITEID = PR.siteId " .
            "WHERE S.SITEID";

        if( $siteId )
        {
            $sSql .= "   AND PR.siteId = " . $siteId . " ";
        }

        $pResult = $this->ExecuteSQL( $sSql );
        return $pResult;
    }


$db = new DatabaseInfinity();

$action = $_REQUEST["action"];

//$action = "SEARCH"; // TEMPORARY
$siteId = $_REQUEST["siteId"];

if( $action == "SEARCH" )
{
    $faceplates = $db->GetFaceplates( $siteId );

    while( $faceplate = FetchObject( $faceplates ) )
    {
        $tpl->newBlock( "FACEPLATE");
        $tpl->assign( "ID", $faceplate->faceplateId );
        $tpl->assign( "PREMISEID", $faceplate->premiseId  );
        $tpl->assign( "ADDRESS", $faceplate->fullAddress );
        $tpl->assign( "SITEID", $faceplate->siteId );
        $tpl->assign( "SITENAME", $faceplate->siteName );
        $tpl->assign( "FEXISTS", $faceplate->faceplateExists );
        $tpl->assign( "FINSTALED", $faceplate->faceplateInstalled );
    }
}
```

Comment: The data are stored as an array? Or as a string...?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: Which leaves everyone guess, *don't it Sam?* - @JayBlanchard now an answer was posted and getting something *after the fact*. Oufff!

Comment: Why can't you post all necessary information while posting the question. I really fed up .... agggg!!!!!

Comment: Sorry guys because of this I'm new here :( I just edited the question and I hope this is enough

Answer (score 0):

Per your edited post, you can change your query and include the condition `faceplateExists <> faceplateInstalled` in a outer query to get the desired result like below

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT F.id AS faceplateId, PR.premiseId, 
ComposeAddressFromPAF( PR.postAddressId ) AS fullAddress, " .
            "   IF( F.id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0 ) AS faceplateExists, " .
            "   IFNULL( F.installed, 0 ) AS faceplateInstalled, " .
            "   PR.siteId, S.NAME AS siteName " .
            "FROM ho_crm_premise PR " .
            "   LEFT JOIN ho_faceplate F ON F.premiseId = PR.premiseId " .
            "   INNER JOIN bcube_site S ON S.SITEID = PR.siteId " .
            "WHERE S.SITEID
) XXX WHERE faceplateExists <> faceplateInstalled;
```

Comment: i'v done LEFT JOIN so I dont have one table where can I do that. And i don't want to delete records I just want not to show them

Comment: @MilosMarkovic, that should be let known to people earlier, anyways see edit in answer if that helps.